# Linking different JFrames

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to create an application in Java and I'm not sure about how to go about creating a screen that will then load another screen, for example a menu screen that when you click a button will load another screen and stop loading the menu screen. What would be the professional way of doing this?

I had the idea of creating different `JFrame` windows and then using `jfrm.dispose()` and `new jfrm.setVisible(true)`, however when doing this there is a split second where there is nothing loaded at all and it doesn't look like a professional app, also I've read that using multiple frames is bad.

I could use different panels and load them when required onto the same frame. Or is there another more efficient way?

Comment: *"..I've read that using multiple frames is bad."* For the best link on that, see.. [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `JInternalFrame`.

- Use `JFrame` as the main window.
- Add `JDesktopPane` below the main menu.
- Use tabbed pane to add tabs. To add tabs to the tabbed pane refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36633721/6204318).

Use the method `addOnScreen(JInternalFrame inFrame, String title)` to add the internal frame as a tab with a title.